# Force install APKs without ADB or Play Store or PackageInstaller app on a phone (Gabb Z2)

Tags: applications, installation, apk, gabb

The phone is Gabb Z2. How would I go about forcing an install of an APK without ADB or Play Store or PackageInstaller app on a phone?

Comment: You tagged this as `root-access`... do you actually have root access and a terminal program? Can you write data to /system/app folder?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. This question has been asked before and there's no solution to it because the vendor always tried to patch up the hack when it's published on the internet.